# How to automatically make POST REST API requests in c#

Tags: c#, rest, post, console-application, azure-data-factory

I have a project scenario that requires me to make POST REST API requests to url endpoints automatically, so basically I have a view/table in my SQL database and I want to iterate through that view/table to find what changed for a specific column(email) and make a POST request to update only what was changed from view/table columns in SQL and update the JSON in the url endpoint for column(email)
This needs to be done automatically either daily, weekly, or monthly.

Here is a snippet of JSON structure and the column that I want to overwrite is (emailAddress)

```js
{
  "additionalAddressInformation": "",
  "addressLine": "ADF Test Street",
  "addressLine1": "",
  "alternatePhone": "",
  "city": "TEST",
  "companyLocationID": null,
  "countryID": 00,
  "emailAddress": "adftestingautotask@test.com",
  "emailAddress2": null,
  "emailAddress3": null,
  "extension": "",
  "externalID": "",
  "facebookUrl": "",
  "faxNumber": "",
  "firstName": "Azure Data Factory",
  "isActive": 0,
  "isOptedOutFromBulkEmail": false,
  "lastName": "Azure",
  "linkedInUrl": "",
  "middleInitial": "B",
  "mobilePhone": "",
  "namePrefix": null,
  "nameSuffix": null,
  "note": "",
  "receivesEmailNotifications": true,
  "phone": "(000) 000-000",
  "primaryContact": false,
  "roomNumber": "",
  "state": "NY",
  "title": "ADF Developer",
  "twitterUrl": "",
  "zipCode": "0000",
}
```

What I have done so far:

1. I have made some researches and came across a library called HangFire, not sure if is the correct way to approach my project scenario.
2. I have created a pipeline in Azure Data Factory and was able to POST manually, but I am not sure if I can use Web activity to create the POST call to include column (email) in the POST call as a parameter or variable.
   Any recommendation or suggestions would help.
   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HangFire is one of the methods - if you prefer creating an app that takes care of it's own and just runs on server - it's more then enough.

Alternative approach would be to use tools like Jenkins  to schedule a repeating task on the server side.

It all depends in this case on preference and available resources - more complicated but self-sufficient app vs simpler app that just scan the db and use post fired up by third party solution.

And please, do mind that my answer is opinion-based - I don't think that there is a one *proper* way of handling this situation without going into much detail.